# HTML como abrir url armazenada em uma variável

Tags: html, node.js

Nao tenho muito conhecimento em html, estou querendo abrir um link que fica armazenado em uma variavel porem sem sucesso.

```
<div class="csgo-item--inspectLink">
      <img src="static/img/inspect.png" href="{{item.inspect}}" target="_blank"style="width:16px;">
</div>
```

o link fica na variavel item.inspect se eu coloco para mostrar oque tem dentro da variavel ele mostra o link certo porem nao sei como fazer para quando clicar na imagem abrir o link em uma nova guia.

nao sei se é importante mas aqui está a css:

```
.csgo-item--inspectLink{
 position: absolute;
top: 5px; left: 5px;

padding: 1px 3px;
z-index: 2;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso você deve utilizar a tag `<a></a>` com o atributo href da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="csgo-item--inspectLink">
      <a href="{{item.inspect}}"><img src="static/img/inspect.png" href="" target="_blank"style="width:16px;"></a>
</div>
```

O href não é um atributo da tag `<img>` mas sim da tag a [clique aqui para mais informações](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A forma correta é você usar a tag de link primeiro e depois colocar a imagem dentro. Ficando assim:

```
  <a href="{{item.inspect}}"><img src="static/img/inspect.png" target="_blank"style="width:16px;"></a>
```

Comment: quando faço isso ele abre esse link:http://localhost:8080/%7B%7Bitem.inspect%7D%7D

Comment: Poderia mandar a declaração dessa variável ?

Comment: a variavel vem de um modulo assim:
    {
  "appid": 730,
  "item_type": {
    "name": "weapon"
  },
  "inspect": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198103002114A12585917845D64323950943037245",
 }

Comment: no caso quero apenas o link:
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_pre‌​view%20S765611981030‌​02114A12585917845D64‌​323950943037245
no caso entao item.inspect

Comment: Poderia mandar um trecho ?